# Join two collections with id stored in array of objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two collections with name **School** & **Student**s

**School Collection**

```
   {
      _id: ObjectId("60008e81d186a82fdc4ff2b7"),
      name: String,
      branch: String,  
      class: [{
             "active" : true,
             "_id" : ObjectId("6001e6871d985e477b61b43f"),
             "name" : "I",
             "order" : 1
        }, 
        {
             "active" : true,
             "_id" : ObjectId("6001e68f1d985e477b61b444"),
             "name" : "II",
             "order" : 2
        }]
   }
```

**Student Collection**

```
  {
      _id: ObjectId("6002def815eccd53a596f830"),
      schoolId: ObjectId("60008e81d186a82fdc4ff2b7"),
      sessionId: ObjectId("60008e81d186a82fdc4ff2b9"),
      class: ObjectId("6001e6871d985e477b61b43f"),
   }
```

I want to get the data of **Student Collection** in single query.

I have class `id` stored in Student Collection and data against that `id` is stored in School Collection under class key, which is array of objects.

Can you please help me in getting the class object in student collection with this id?

Output i want:

```
data: {
  _id: ObjectId("6002def815eccd53a596f830"),
  schoolId: ObjectId("60008e81d186a82fdc4ff2b7"),
  sessionId: ObjectId("60008e81d186a82fdc4ff2b9"),
  class: ObjectId("6001e6871d985e477b61b43f"),
  classData: [{
        "active" : true,
        "_id" : ObjectId("6001e6871d985e477b61b43f"),
        "name" : "I",
        "order" : 1
    }]
```

}

So I tried this but it didn't work:

```
const students = await this.studentModel.aggregate([
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'School',
    let: { classId: '$class' },
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: { $eq: ['$$classId', '$class._id'] },
        },
      },
    ],
    as: 'classData',
  },
},
]);
```

Comment: try `$in` instead of `$eq` in your query.

Comment: @turivishal i tried it didn't worked

Comment: make sure collection name `School` or `Schools` in database.

Comment: yes both of them are School and Student, problem is with query.

Comment: query looks good when you use `$in` instead of `$eq`, tested in local machine.

Comment: i am getting empty array, and i want this object in key classData {
             "active" : true,
             "_id" : ObjectId("6001e6871d985e477b61b43f"),
             "name" : "I",
             "order" : 1
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227597/discussion-between-deepak-tyagi-and-turivishal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$lookup`, pass `schoolId` and `class` in `let`,
- `$match` school id condition
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `class` and filter specific class object
- `$arrayElemAt` will get object from returned result from `$filter`
- `$replaceRoot` to replace object to root

```
const students = await this.studentModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "School",
      let: {
        schoolId: "$schoolId",
        classId: "$class"
      },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$schoolId", "$_id"] } } },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$class",
                    cond: { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$classId"] }
                  }
                },
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "classData"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/usLlzuGH9Ga)